# Calling a static method inside a class in python

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I run into a situation, where I call a static method of a class from another static method. To be sure, that I don't ask an X-Y-question, I'm trying to give some background.

I have a class, that holds a data container and several methods to convert data inside the container. As I also want the converters to be callable from the outside without a class instance, I choose static methods:

```
class SomeClass(object):

  def __init__(self,some_data):
    self.data = some_data

  @staticmethod
  def convert_1(data_item):
    return 1+data_item

  @staticmethod
  def convert_2(data_item):
    return 2*data_item
```

Now I can do `SomeClass.convert_1(data_item)` without the need to create an instance of `SomeClass`.

Let's say, I want to have a method inside `SomeClass`, that does the two converts successively, and also want to have that method as a static method.

Can I do

```
@staticmethod
def combined_convert(data_item):
  data_item = SomeClass.convert_1(data_item)
  data_item = SomeClass.convert_2(data_item)
  return data_item
```

inside `SomeClass`? This feels wrong, as I call the class inside its own definition, but I cannot come up with another 'more pythonic' way.

Comment: The class is defined by the time you get to execute `combined_convert` so there is no problem.

Comment: You reference *instances* of the class from methods all the time (with `self`); why should referencing the class be a problem? It's just the top-level code within a `class` statement that cannot refer to the class under construction.

Comment: Have you tried using top-level functions inside modules? Looks like you are trying to use classes for namespacing

Comment: @Felk actually yes. Factoring out the static methods into top-level functions would be a solution. I feel, this is more a design choice. Or are there more caveats?

Comment: using modules for this is just idiomatic python. Using static methods in classes is usually just more typing and has no benefits, except if it's a factory method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class method.

```
@classmethod
def combined_convert(cls,data_item):
    data_item = cls.convert_1(data_item)
    data_item = cls.convert_2(data_item)
    return data_item
```

Comment: I fee, this is wrong, cause I cannot call this method from the outside withouth passing an instance, or can I?

Comment: You can call the method outside without instance

Comment: If you access the class itself and want to be able to refactor the code more easily, this is the way to go, because `@classmethod`-decorated methods are static, but automagically get the class passed as a first argument, which then can be used instead of repeating the class name. If you want a pure static method however, there's `@staticmethod`, which injects no arguments by itself